# VIM, mapping, Why doesnt nmap <Alt><Right> <C-w><Right> work?

Tags: vim, mapping

How can i use ALT key in key mapping? 
And how can i make double key commands? for example i tried

```
<Alt-Right> <C-w><Right>
```

and it didnt work either.
And as far as i know, some keys are bad to be used for mapping in VIM, Space key for example. if possible, write also please keys which usually do not work in key mapping in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in a graphical Vim (GVim, MacVim):

```
nnoremap <M-Right> <C-w><Right>
```

"Alt" is a new invention, which Vim doesn't know - it knows about "Meta", a key that once existed, and keeps calling the newfangled invention by the old key's name.

However, terminal is trickier, as <kbd>Alt-Right</kbd> is typically bound to some key sequence that is useful in Terminal, like <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> (move one word right); you can see what it is in Vim by preceding it by <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>: `nnoremap`<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Alt-Right</kbd>`<C-w><Right>`, which will probably come out as

```
nnoremap ^[f <C-w><Right>
```